# Using React-Table and Fetch GET JSON to create a dynamic table with columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-table

Hi new to React and I'm trying to create a table using React-Table with automatic columns using JSON data via fetch response.

I have an example of a table being created based on a fetch get

```
componentDidMount(){
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
    fetch(url,{
      method: "GET"
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
      this.setState({posts: result })
    })
  }
```

however, you need to specify the accessors, which is not practical for large datasets.
Here is the code sandbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/embed/goofy-dew-u94bu

I have another example of a table with automatic columns, however, the JSON is hard coded so I have no idea how to work with the fetch response to assign it to a global to make it "hardcoded" because it's asynchronous.

Here is the code sandbox for it.  https://codesandbox.io/s/static-fnn42

in this example, it successfully creates the table based on initial_data, however, when I uncomment componenetDidMount, and replace "this.state.initial_data" with "this.state.posts" there is an error

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    posts: [],
    value: '',
    initial_data: [
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
},
]
  }
}

/*
componentDidMount(){
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  fetch(url,{
    method: "GET"
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(posts => {
    this.setState({posts: response.posts})
  })
}
*/


getColumns() {
  return Object.keys(this.state.initial_data[0]).map(key => {
    return {
      Header: key,
      accessor: key
    };
  });
}

render() {
  const columns = this.getColumns();
 // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.initial_data));
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTable
        data={this.state.initial_data}
        columns={columns}
        defaultPageSize={10}
        className="-striped -highlight"
        filterable
      />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( <
App / > ,
document.getElementById('app')
);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the function below, there is an error when you replace "this.state.initial_data" with "this.state.posts[0]", it says the object is NULL, which is presumably because once it's out of the FETCH get, the data because undefined based on the aync nature of it. If it is, how do I bypass this?

```
getColumns() {
    return Object.keys(this.state.initial_data[0]).map(key => {
      return {
        Header: key,
        accessor: key
      };
    });
```

I also think there is a problem with the state of "posts: []" as well, as when I log it, it shows [], then [object], for the hardcoded example, it just shows [Object].

I'm open to other solution/libraries to make it work. If you could have your solution in codesandbox, jsfiddle, codepen, etc, it'd be awesome! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition in your `getColumns()` method so that `Object.keys` will execute only when `this.state.posts[0]` has some data like -

```
  getColumns() {
    const getPostKeys = this.state.posts[0];
    if (getPostKeys) {
      const column =
        this.state.posts &&
        Object.keys(getPostKeys).map(key => {
          return {
            Header: key,
            accessor: key
          };
        });
      return column;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Working Example - https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-clarke-ln7wx